# Where does Odoo save the contents of My Dashboard

Tags: odoo, dashboard, openerp-8

I need to know where Odoo saves the views that will be shown in (My Dashboard) when we click (Add to My Dashboard).

I looked in the table scheme and I could only find one related table: **board_create**
which is used to save the custom dashboards the user creates.

But I only want to find out where the contents (the views not the data) of the default Dashboard are saved in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenERP 7 and 8 you can find the view for dashboard in 'ir_ui_view_custom' table.
The view will be saved inside 'arch' column.

From OpenERP web interface this is will happened when you click 'add to my dashboard'

1. Javascript will invoke 'add_dashboard'
2. Javascript will make rpc request using '/board/add_to_dashboard' to openerp server
3. Openerp server will invoke "add_to_dashboard" function
4. Openerp server will save the view inside 'ir_ui_view_custom' table

Openerp use these files to process 'add to my dashboard'

1. /OpenErp7/addons/board/static/src/js/dashboard.js
2. /OpenErp7/src/main/openerp/addons/board/controllers.py

I hope this help.