# Customize Sales Dashboard using Inheritance (Odoo 10)

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I am customizing the Sales Dashboard in Odoo 10. I want to set  container i.e "invoiced" so that it displays the values from custom module.

First, I am unable to find exact xpath because i dont see this defined in the view. (the view is attached below)

Secondly, I want to display the values for the current user logged. Can anyone suggest me something?

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sales_targets_kanban_inherit_id">
        <field name="name">Sales Target Kanban Inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.team</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.crm_team_salesteams_view_kanban"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//field[@name='invoiced']" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
             </xpath>    
             <xpath expr="//field[@name='invoiced_target']" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
             </xpath>        

        </field>
</record>
```

[image]

I want to display my custom module-> field in that "click to set". Will this be done through python or xml
Hopes for suggestion

Comment: Use this as a reference to find and show us the code for your dashboard and then we can answer how to display the values you want in it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161623/where-does-odoo-save-the-contents-of-my-dashboard?rq=1

Comment: im trying to inherit the dashboard view to make changes but not succeeded .